# How can I hide a user from the Wikipedia "Recent changes" page?

Tags: javascript, css, userscripts

I need to hide all the contributions of a particular user. (e.g. "‎Adumbrativus") from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:RecentChanges?hidebots=1&hidecategorization=1&hideWikibase=1&limit=50&days=7&urlversion=2).

So this entry will be hidden.

```
25 December 2022
Javaris Crittenton‎ 10:34  −23‎  ‎Adumbrativus talk contribs‎ (Remove "convicted murderer"; the charge was dropped)
```

I am already [using a similar script](https://github.com/larsks/sx-question-filter/blob/master/sx-hide-questions.user.js) with Tampermonkey.

I am trying to find what changes needs to be done in this script so that it will hide the user on Wikipedia recent changes page.

---

Update:

I am using this script on a non-english wikipedia and I am able to hide the username. But I need to hide the entire line and not just username.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hide usernames from the "Recent changes" page
// @description  Hide usernames on non english wikis
// @version      0.1
// @author       double-beep
// @match        https://mr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B7:%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%A1%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B2_%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%B2*
// @require      https://gist.githubusercontent.com/BrockA/2625891/raw/waitForKeyElements.js
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js
//
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=wikipedia.org
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* globals waitForKeyElements */

(function() {
    const blacklisted = ['अभय नातू', 'InternetArchiveBot'];

    waitForKeyElements('.mw-changeslist-line-inner-userLink', ([element]) => {
        const userLink = element.querySelector('.mw-userlink');
        const username = userLink?.textContent.trim();

        if (!blacklisted.includes(username)) return; // not blacklisted

        element.style.display = 'none';
    }, false);
})();
```

Comment: The selector in `waitForKeyElements` should match a line, not a username.

Comment: I don't get why you started the bounty. You haven't replied to the feedback given to you.

Comment: Because I did not understand how to match a line :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following userscript uses [`waitForKeyElements`](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891/), a utility developed by [Brock Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331508/brock-adams) and modified by me that searches for new elements after the page has been loaded. This way, even if a blacklisted user makes a change *after* the page has been loaded, the contribution will still be hidden.

Fill the `blacklisted` array with users whose name you want to hide.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hide usernames from the "Recent changes" page
// @version      0.1
// @author       double-beep
// @match        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:RecentChanges*
// @require      https://gist.githubusercontent.com/double-beep/c4d4ec3866e5e54ae514c0aab60af242/raw/waitForKeyElements.js
//
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=wikipedia.org
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* globals waitForKeyElements */

(function() {
    const blacklisted = ['InternetArchiveBot'];

    waitForKeyElements('.special li', element => {
        const userLink = element.querySelector('.mw-userlink');
        const username = userLink?.textContent.trim();

        if (!blacklisted.includes(username)) return; // not blacklisted

        element.style.display = 'none';
    }, false);
})();
```

Comment: This solution worked after I reset the chrome using an option "Restore settings to their original defaults".

Answer (score 1):

I assume double-beep's solution works, but I myself haven't been using `waitForKeyElements` for a very long time, it uses an old "approach" to look for DOM changes (e.g. `setInterval()`) that is very outdated IMHO (we have [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)).

Alternatively here is a working userscript that has NO dependencies (e.g. no `waitForKeyElements` and no `jQuery` which is a required dependency for the former afaik), besides that, the concept/logic is basically the same:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Wikipedia Recent Changes Ignorelist
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Just an example for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74911619/how-can-i-hide-a-user-from-the-wikipedia-recent-changes-page
// @author       exside
// @match        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:RecentChanges*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=tampermonkey.net
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Helper method to facilitate waiting for a DOM mutations and run a callback function.
     *
     * @usage `when('<selector>', (el) => { console.log('I have arrived!', el); }, <optional:targetNode>);`
     *
     * @param {String} selector - The CSS selector to wait for.
     * @param {Function} fn - The callback function to call when the element appears.
     * @param {HTMLElement} targetNode - The node to watch for mutations within.
     */
    const when = function(selector, fn, targetNode = document.body) {
        return (new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => [...mutations]
            .flatMap((mutation) => [...mutation.addedNodes])
            .filter((node) => node.matches && node.matches(selector))
            .forEach(fn.bind(observer))
        )).observe(targetNode, { childList: true, subtree: true });
    };

    const ignore = ['user1', 'bot2'];

    when('ul', (el) => {
        el.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((li) => {
            if ( ignore.includes((li.querySelector('.mw-userlink'))?.textContent.trim()) ) {
                li.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    }, document.querySelector('.mw-changeslist'));
})();
```

Comment: This works on English wikipedia (so does double-beep's solution). But does not work on marathi (mr) wikipedia recent changes page.

Comment: just checked the marathi page, the HTML structure is the same as on the english one, so i don't see why it wouldn't work? you mean it does not do anything (e.g. hiding rows)? you'll have to adapt the @match config to the mr URL of course, did you do that?

Comment: Yes. I matched the URL and still it does not change the page (i.e. hiding rows for the user "InternetArchiveBot". There was no error in console.

Comment: You're probably right - I've modified the original version of `waitForKeyElements` to remove jQuery and use `MutationObserver`s. The reason your answer doesn't work for the OP is because you search for new elements, but don't scan those that already exist on page load.